# How to remove columns and rows that sum to 0 while preserving non-numeric columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Below is a subset of my data. I am trying to remove columns AND rows that sum to 0 ... the catch is that I want to preserve columns 1 to 8 in the resulting output. Any ideas? I've tried quite a few. A tidy solution would be best.

```
Site    Date    Mon Day Yr          Szn SznYr       A   B   C   D   E   F   G
B0001   7/29/97 7   29  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
B0001   7/29/97 7   29  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   1   0   0   0   0
B0001   7/29/97 7   29  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   0   3   0   0   0
B0001   7/29/97 7   29  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   0   0   0   0   10
B0002   7/28/97 7   28  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   0   0   5   0   0
B0002   7/28/97 7   28  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
B0002   7/28/97 7   28  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   0   0   0   6   0
B0002   7/28/97 7   28  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
B0002   7/28/97 7   28  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
B0002   7/28/97 7   28  1997    Summer  1997-Summer 0   0   0   0   0   0   8
B0002   6/28/07 6   28  2007    Summer  2007-Summer 0   3   6   1   7   0   1
```

Comment: none of those columns sums to zero

Comment: should we check the sum for columns before checking the sum for rows ? The output might be different depending on our order of removal.

Comment: edited the data to make it what I wanted to show. I am not sure if the order would matter.

Comment: Just fyi, I changed the tidyverse tag to dplyr. The tidyverse tag wiki will show you that it's reserved for development of that ecosystem of packages, not general use of those packages. Feel free to correct if dplyr is an inaccurate tag.

Comment: We should remove rows first!

Comment: Can you add the output you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
# remove rows 
df <- df[rowSums(df[-(1:7)]) !=0, ]
# remove columns    
df <- df[c(1:7,7 + which(colSums(df[-(1:7)]) !=0))]
#     Site    Date Mon Day   Yr    Szn       SznYr B C D E F  G
# 2  B0001 7/29/97   7  29 1997 Summer 1997-Summer 0 1 0 0 0  0
# 3  B0001 7/29/97   7  29 1997 Summer 1997-Summer 0 0 3 0 0  0
# 4  B0001 7/29/97   7  29 1997 Summer 1997-Summer 0 0 0 0 0 10
# 5  B0002 7/28/97   7  28 1997 Summer 1997-Summer 0 0 0 5 0  0
# 7  B0002 7/28/97   7  28 1997 Summer 1997-Summer 0 0 0 0 6  0
# 10 B0002 7/28/97   7  28 1997 Summer 1997-Summer 0 0 0 0 0  8
# 11 B0002 6/28/07   6  28 2007 Summer 2007-Summer 3 6 1 7 0  1
```

You can do this in one step to get the same output as @dan-y (the same in this specific case, but different if you have negative values in your real data) :

```
    df <- df[rowSums(df[-(1:7)]) !=0,
             c(1:7,7 + which(colSums(df[-(1:7)]) !=0))]
```

Comment: This works! Curious about the syntax. What does the minus do?

Comment: with negative indices you mention the columns that you don't want to keep, so `df[-(1:8)]` keep all columns except 8 first ones

Answer (score 2):

This isn't fancy, but it's explicit and easily modifiable:

```
# generate example data
df <- data.frame(
    site = c(rep("B1", 4), rep("B2", 7)),
    szn  = rep("Summar", 11),
    A= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    B= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3),
    C= c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6),
    D= c(0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
    E= c(0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,7),
    F= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0),
    G= c(0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# get names of cols you want to check for 0s
other_cols <- names(df)[1:2]
num_cols   <- names(df)[3:9]

# check rowsum and colsum
rows_to_keep <- rowSums(df[ , num_cols]) != 0
cols_to_keep <- colSums(df[ , num_cols]) != 0

# keep (1) rows that don't sum to zero 
#      (2) numeric cols that don't sum to zero, and
#      (3) the "other" cols that are non-numeric
df[rows_to_keep , c(other_cols, num_cols[cols_to_keep])]
```

Comment: You don't need `names`, only `other_cols <- 1:2` and `num_cols   <- 3:9` will do. Upvote.

Comment: Note that it might give a different output from mine, as I check which columns to remove after removing rows.