# dissimilarity of community matrix with many samples equal zero, vegan package

Tags: vegan

I have community dataset for macrofauna associated with corals that I am struggling to analyze it in vegan package.

Coral colonies were imaged in 2015 (for two coral species at five sites) and we counted macrofauna species found on each colony. In 2016 and 2017, we revisited the same coral colonies to count associated fauna. So far, this is a repeated measure experiment (Year/colonyID), but I have two problems:

1- some of the revisited colonies in 2016 and 2017 had no fauna (143 out of 686 total colonies) meaning we have zero samples (n=143). This caused a problem in `adonis` function to test the dissimilarity.

`adonis(F_Mat ~ Species+Site+Year, data = F_Meta, permutations = 9999)
you have empty rows: their dissimilarities may be meaningless in method �bray�missing values in results`

I understand this message, but I  must account for zero samples as they represent the dynamic of fauna community over time. I tried "bray" and "Jaccard" methods but both give me the same error message as above.

I used `log1p (1+F_Mat )` to replace zeros to transform my values and replace zeros, but it did not work to calculate alpha diversity; `Chaol` diversity index, but worked for `adonis` function. To cope with that, I used `dist.zeroes` function in `BiodiversityR` package to deal with `adonis`, and use abundance matrix for the alpha diversity. Not sure if it the right approach though

2- Some colonies in 2015 could not be found in later years (2016 and 2017), and instead, we took images for new colonies in 2016 and 2017 that have **not** been visited previously. So, it is not really repeated measure and I think we should account for colony ID as a random effect instead, but this is not doable in vegan to my knowledge.

Any advice on how to analyze this dataset and troubleshoot my experimental problems? Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://rdrr.io/cran/vegan/man/vegdist.html

`In principle, you cannot study species composition without species and you should remove empty sites from community data.` Since vegdist is passed to adonis I believe this statement carries through.

A potential solution might be adding a dummy species that has a constant value for each site.

If you end up needing to remove these rows or columns that sum to 0 you can reference this question [How to remove columns and rows that sum to 0 while preserving non-numeric columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825436/how-to-remove-columns-and-rows-that-sum-to-0-while-preserving-non-numeric-column)

```
df <- df[rowSums(df[-(1:7)]) !=0, ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but instead of adding random dummy numbers, I used ```sqrt (1+x)``` to transform all data and keep the same distance between them and overcome zero problems. I think this is a valid and acceptable approach to deal with this dataset.