# Finding a consistent method to filter multivariate data in R

Tags: r

This question involves multivariate ecology and will be using a Site x Species matrix as an example. Overall, this question looks for ways to remove certain data within the dataframe. We have 5 Species as columns, one column as the Site Code, and 9 Sites as rows. Ideally, the result of removed data would be extractable into a vector for use as a separate dataframe at a later time. I have tried to use code from other Stack questions to achieve these objectives, however I have been unable to discover a single kind of syntax that works across the board. Please advise.

```
df <- structure(list(Site = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I"), X1= c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L), X2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L), X3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L), X4 = c(0L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), X5 = c(6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

1. Remove columns that have only one instance in the dataset.
2. Remove columns that sum to less than 6.
3. Remove rows with one instance in the dataset.
4. Remove rows that sum to less than 10.

Examples that don't directly address the context of the question and how each objective is interconnected. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754119/r-remove-rows-from-dataframe-that-contain-only-zeros-in-numeric-columns-base)  [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825436/how-to-remove-columns-and-rows-that-sum-to-0-while-preserving-non-numeric-column)

Comment: Do you mean "Always retain the first *of* multiple ID columns if present."? What is the ID column? `SITE`? Or do you mean, "Always retain the first row for each `SITE`"? Or do you mean "Retain the first row for each `SITE` if no rows for that site would be retained otherwise."?

Comment: Please clarify "Remove sites (rows) with one or less than 3 species."

Comment: The ID column is Site, you are correct. I mean to do the filtering without messing with the first column. Removing sites with 3 species means a site with values for 3 columns (Species)

Comment: It's still unclear. Can you give an example that shows each of the filter rules being applied?

Comment: Did the edits clarify? I switched it up a bit..

Comment: Are the filters to be applied sequentially? For example are you checking for rows with only one instance (non-zero? sum to 1?) *before* or *after* removing columns? Showing how each of the rules would be applied to your example data would go a long way in clarifying.

Comment: I think that having the code for each of the 4 questions might just work. Generally I would remove columns with either 1 instance or sum to ## and then I would remove the rows that have either 1 instance or sun to ##.